# Change font color on a =org-reveal= slide

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-reveal

I'm preparing a set of lectures using =org-reveal=. I found really useful to change the background to add exercise to the slides, e.g.,

```
** EXERCISE
:PROPERTIES:
:reveal_background: ./images/Thinker-30.png
:reveal_background_trans: slide
:END:
Using the analogy with the river, prove the Gauß' theorem in:
- Cartesian coordinates,
- Cylindrical coordinates, and
- Spherical coordinates.
```

but the result is not very visible....
[image]

### Question:

Is it possible to change the font color for this slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from another question ([Answer from Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580169/changing-color-of-text-in-html-export-from-org-mode)), but it works with org-reveal, it uses a Macro. If you want to do it for the whole document, I guess it would be easier to modify the css file.

```
#+MACRO: color @@html:<font color="$1">$2</font>@@

* This is a test

This is a sample sentence in normal text color.

{{{color(red,This is a sample sentence in red text color.)}}}

{{{color(green,This is a sample sentence in green text color.)}}}
```